# Where is the php.ini file located in aws lightsail linux

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail, adsapi-php.ini

I want to migrate one of my websites to AWS lightsail and I need access the php.ini file. I have found a php.ini file located in opt/bitnami/php/etc/ but all the changes I do to that file doesn't reflect on the server. 
I'm using the "bitnami" user.
I have tried to restart the apache server with the command

`sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache`

I have even tried to reboot the lightsail instance but it's still not reflecting.
I tried to run the command

    `php --ini` 

and it shows that the php.ini configuration file is located in /bitnami/lamp71stack-linux-x64/output/php/lib but I cannot find that path on my lightsail linux server.
[php --ini resutlt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23Y00.png)

Comment: [Strangly the best place to look would be the AWS Forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=783185)

Comment: [Or maybe](https://community.bitnami.com/t/cant-edit-php-ini-to-modify-the-execution-time-bitnami-aws/25883)